# How do you add an extended function to an array in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, extends

I am trying desperately to add a simple function to the array type, but nothing I have done has worked.

I have seen this method

```js
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    functionName(): any
}

Array.prototype.functionName = function() {
  DO SOMETHING
}
```

which compiles but fails at runtime, declaring that "functionName is not a function".

I have also tried this method:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  functionName() {
    DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

but typescript won't build that, giving me the error "Property 'functionName' is missing in type '()[]' but required in type 'MyArray'.

This feels like it should be way more simple than it is, and I'm tearing my hair out to get it to work.

Comment: This is somewhat of an anti-pattern in JavaScript

Comment: It's hard to see what the issue is without seeing how you use it. The file that is monkeypatching `Array.prototype` needs to be imported before you can write `[].functionName()`